# Parsing double numbers and millions

Tags: java, double, number-formatting

I have a file that represents numbers of millions like this `29.879.999` and double numbers like this `28.09`. I am trying to parse them using `NumberFormat` and convert them all(integer and double) to `double`. Here is what i wrote:

```
for (String[] entry : data) {
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance();
Number value = nf.parse(entry[4]).doubleValue();
System.out.println("closingvalue: "+value);
}
```

The results are:

```
closingvalue  2925.0
closingvalue  2.9879999E7
closingvalue  2809.0
closingvalue  2.7219999E7
closingvalue  2.5969999E7
closingvalue  2491.0
closingvalue  2635.0
closingvalue  2591.0
```

The input file is like this:

```
Date;Open;High;Low;Close;Log Return
2/1/2009;31.190.001;31.639.999;30.469.999;31.35;-
5/1/2009;30.73;30.77;29.08;29.25;-0.0693
6/1/2009;29.790.001;30.42;29.51;29.879.999;0.0213
7/1/2009;29.15;29.40;28.00;28.09;-0.0618
8/1/2009;27.90;27.950.001;26.860.001;27.219.999;-0.0315
```

I want to parse them all as `double` like `28.09` even the millions. Any help is appreciated.Thank you!

Comment: Does the file contain numbers in the range 1000-999999? (as in, numbers that look like 1.000-999.999) How would you distinguish those from doubles?

Comment: it represents thousands like this 20.000, millons like this 120.000.000 and decimal numbers like this 30.42 or -0.0315

Comment: So how do you know that "20.000" means "20 thousand" and not "20, to 3 decimal places of precision"?

Comment: So you want to determine the format for large values using a `NumberFormat` rather than use the default format?

Comment: 26.000.000 or 20.68 both are supposed to be the closing value of a stock. How am i going to determine a specific format?

Comment: I'm confused... so both the decimal separator and the thousands separator is "."?  can a decimal number be bigger than 1000 (e.g.  1.234.56 where 56 is the decimal)?

Comment: @flower can you edit your question to put some of your different formatted inputs ?

Comment: @AngelKoh i am not sure what it is. I assume it is million 1 million 234 thousands 56, than 1 thousand 256 point 36

Comment: @ Bolzano yes i am goint to edit to add the input file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming that the following is a valid format

```
contains decimals
0.<any number> 
-0.<any number>
1.234.567.89 (last third digit is ".")

all others are integers.
```

then all you have to do is change the 3 decimal conditions to ",". This will change your numbers to

```
0,<any number>
-0,<any number>
1.234.567,89 (last third digit is now ",")
```

and use the Locale.GERMANY to do your parsing

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.GERMANY);
Double parsedNumber = nf.parse(value[4]).doubleValue();
```

EDIT: this is what i'd do to convert the decimals.

```
String testString = value[4];
if(testString.size() >= 3){  //must be at least 3 digits
    int last3rdPosition = testString.size() - 3; 

    if(testString.charAt(last3rdPosition) == '.'){

         //check if the last third char is "."
         //handle cases like 31.35 (change it to 31,35)
         testString.setChar(last3rdPosition, ',');
    } else if (testString.charAt(0) == '0' 
               && testString.charAt(1) == '.'){

         //handle cases like 0.0213 (change it to 0,0213)
         testString.setChar(1, ',')
    }else if (testString.charAt(0) == '-' 
               && testString.charAt(1) == '0'
               && testString.charAt(2) == '.'){

         //handle cases like -0.0315 (change it to -0,0315)
         testString.setChar(2, ',')
    } 

}  
// do converting as per normal using Locale.GERMANY
// Locale.GERMANY will treat "." as the thousands separator
//                       and "," as the decimal separator
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.GERMANY);
Double parsedNumber = nf.parse(testString).doubleValue();
```

Comment: I get the results like this: 
closingvalue  2925.0
closingvalue  2.9879999E7
closingvalue  2809.0
closingvalue  2.7219999E7
closingvalue  2.5969999E7
closingvalue  2491.0
closingvalue  2635.0
i believe that for example 2491.0 format is wrong because it was supposed to be 24.91

Comment: @flower, you will need to convert string 29.25 to 29,25 first ... do a check to see if the last 3rd digit is a "." if so, change it to ","   - try nf.parse("29,25") directly with a comma?

Comment: i am trying to use  `split(".")` so that i can use the above only for numbers that have more than two "." but it doesn't split at all, it gives zero length.
`for (String[] entry : data) {
   String[] entryparsed = entry[4].split(".");
   for(int i=0; i<entryparsed.length; i++){
    System.out.println(entryparsed[i]);
    
   }
   System.out.println(entryparsed.length);`

Comment: @flower, look at the edit, see if it meets your requirements. basically I check the odd cases, and convert those to the format for Locale.GERMANY

Answer (score 0):

Your values are not doubles but integers (millions or billons) actually because java don't comprehend big numbers with dots. By the way i recomend you `BigInteger` or `BigDecimal` to deal with big numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Use `DecimalFormat` for formatting the text as below.

```
DecimalFormat decimal = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");
System.out.println(decimal.format(487384.321313112));
```

Comment: I tried this nut i get an  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Number 
 `DecimalFormat decimal = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");
  String value = decimal.format(entry[4]);
  System.out.println("closingvalue  "+value);`

Comment: @flower format is not accepting "String" as input. it only accepts primitives and  their object variations like Long, Double, BigDecimal,BigInteger , AtomicInteger  etc ...  according to your problem first you need to parse the inputs.